# Persistir la informacion de un usuario que se ha logueado en React

Tags: reactjs

Estoy realizando un login y registro de usuarios en React con los hooks use context y use reducer.- Mi consulta va orientada a como implementar la persistencia de la informacion de un usuario que se ha logueado durante todo lo que dure su sesion. Hasta ahora solo logro mostrar el nombre de usuario cuando se loguea, pero al actualizar la pagina pierdo esa informacion.

Initial State

```
userActive: null
```

AuthActions

```
   const respuesta = await clienteAxios.post("/api/account/login", datos);
      console.log(respuesta.data);

      Swal.fire("Correcto", "El usuario se logueo correctamente", "success");

      //jwt decode
      const decoded = jwt_decode(respuesta.data.token);
      console.log(decoded.unique_name);

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_EXITOSO,
        payload: {
          token: respuesta.data.token,
          userActive: decoded.unique_name,
        },
      });

      //usuarioAutenticado()
      history.push("/usuarios");  
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      if (error.response.status === 400) {
        ErrorAutenticacion();
      } else if (error.response.status === 500) {
        ErrorServidor();
      }
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_ERROR,
      });
    } finally {
      ocultarSpinner();
    }
```

Auth Reducer

```
 case LOGIN_EXITOSO:
      localStorage.setItem("token", action.payload.token);
      return {
        ...state,
        userActive: action.payload.userActive
      };
    /*case OBTENER_USUARIO:
      return{
        ...state,
        userActive: action.payload
      } 
      */
```

Componente donde quisiera mostrar esa informacion del usuario

```
const { userActive } = authContext;
```

En el use effect de este componente no tengo nada  relacionado a cargar informacion de este usuario cada vez que el componente se monta.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo crear un hook personalizado para poder verificar que hubo una sesión activa, es muy simple de implementar.

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react'

const useRemember = (props) => {
  const { userActive } = useContext(authContext);

  useEffect(()=>{
    const usuario = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuario'));
    if(usuario && !userActive){
      // Logee a su usuario aquí.
    }
  }, [userActive])

  return (<div> Loading ... </div>);
}

export default useRemember
```

Ahora, si ya tienes implementado eso y quieres obtener toda la información que tenías antes, guarda un item con todos los datos

```
json.stringify(datos);
```

En cada acción que ejecutes dentro del reducer, es la única manera de tener el estado global actualizado.